# Calcular el valor maximo de un campo

Tags: mysql

ayuda...! trato de calcular el valor maximo de mi campo ***estatus_condicionante*** para poder colocarlo en uno nuevo llamado **estatus_materia** relacionado con su **id_proyecto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que tengo hasta el momento seria algo asi

```
 SELECT c.`id_proyecto`, c.`id_materia`,
MAX(c.`estatus_condicionante`) AS estatus_materia
FROM calculo_condicionantes AS c
GROUP BY c.`id_proyecto`, c.`id_materia`
ORDER BY c.`id_proyecto`, c.`id_materia`,c.`estatus_condicionante` DESC
```

y tendria un resultado de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hay alguna forma que pueda quedar de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el script de creación de las tablas con sus datos para poder hacer pruebas y ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución sería hacer `SELECT` a la tabla `calculo_condicionantes` y luego un `LEFT JOIN` al resultado de tu consulta.

#### Ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT 
  c.id,
  c.id_proyecto,
  c.id_materia,
  c.estatus_condicionante,
  t.estatus_materia
FROM calculo_condicionantes AS c
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      id_proyecto,
      id_materia,
      MAX(estatus_condicionante) AS estatus_materia
    FROM calculo_condicionantes
    GROUP BY id_proyecto, id_materia
  ) AS t
    ON t.id_proyecto = c.id_proyecto
    AND t.id_materia= c.id_materia
```

Comment: te agradezco mucho , me funciono muy bien